# How do you load gopro footage into Blackmagic Fusion?

Tags: ffmpeg, blackmagic

I'm trying to get started with Fusion. I have h.264 encoded video in a mp4 container. When creating a loader I get an unhelpful error of 'Loader1 failed at time 0'. Googling around I found some mention of not having the codec installed, so I pulled the CCCP and still had no dice.

ffmpeg also seems to be able to work with the files fine. I see some mention of Direct Show in the file format selector, but there is no option in ffmpeg to encode to that.

If I just try and mash a h.264 encoded stream into a container that appears to be supported, like avi, using:

```
ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i preaudio.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc preaudio.avi
```

I get errors that look like:

```
Loader1 failed at time 0
Loader1 failed at time 0
Loader1 failed to load file "<pwd>\preaudio0000.avi" (clip "<pwd>\preaudio.avi" at frame 0)
Loader1 failed at time 0
Loader1 failed to load file "<pwd>\preaudio0000.avi" (clip "<pwd>\preaudio.avi" at frame 0)
Loader1 failed at time 0
Loader1 failed to load file "<pwd>\preaudio0000.avi" (clip "<pwd>\preaudio.avi" at frame 0)
Loader1 failed at time 0
```

Googling Loader failed at time 0 yields nothing.

TLDR; I know nothing and want to get from a file like this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\GOPR0047.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-02-20T21:24:36.000000Z
    firmware        : HD4.01.05.00.00
  Duration: 00:11:49.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 45115 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 44960 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-20T21:24:36.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 21:45:04:55
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-20T21:24:36.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 21:45:04:55
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-20T21:24:36.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 21:45:04:55
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 13 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-02-20T21:24:36.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro SOS
```

To something that Fusion will let me work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End answer was dnxhd/mov. Use something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v dnxhd -b 440M -c:a copy out.mov
```

The -b argument should be adjusted based on your input resolution. 440M is the correct choice for 1080p @ 59.94 fps.